# How can I hide/remove a WPF ColumnHeaderStyle column header?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle issue, in my case I wanted to add these components(textblock, button) to the all columns headers, but generated a wrong/fake column header too, so appear columns with their headers( Dosage + Btn, Drug + Btn, Patient + Btn, Date + Btn), and plus a fake column header with no header name, which contains only a button -> "" + btn.
Datagrid has no predefined columns.
My question is how can I hide/remove/disable or cancel this fake column header?
Any suggests?

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="dgheaderstyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        <Button Content="Click"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource dgheaderstyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="262" Margin="10,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="472">        
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

            DataContext = table;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky issue so bear with me.
The extra DataGridColumn header is named **PART_FillerColumnHeader**. 
It is placed behind the ItemsPresenter located within **PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter**.

A **simplification** of a DataGridTemplate ( not really all it contains but just the relevant parts).

```
  <ControlTemplate>
      <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" 
               Style="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>                                                                 
          <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" />                
     </Grid>      
  </ControlTemplate>
```

our interest is in **DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter** , lets take a look inside.
**Simplified**

```
 <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeadersPresenterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">           
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
            <Grid>                                                                                                                          
               <DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
               <ItemsPresenter />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Now the ItemContainers of [DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheaderspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are of type DataGridColumnHeader. 
When you assign a ColumnHeaderStyle to your DataGrid. It is applied to the Items of DataGridColumnHeaderPresenter and to **PART_FillerColumnHeader** AS WELL.

As shown above **PART_FillerColumnHeader** is placed behind the ItemsPresenter. The Items of ColumnHeadersPresenter are rendered to that ItemsPrsenter (meaning all the other column headers).And that's why you see that extra column header. 
The extra column header you see behind your column headers.

Now how to get rid of it. simple assign it a style of it's own.

You can just copy paste the default one using Blend.