# WPF custom datagrid phantom header overlap

Tags: custom-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have written a custom control which derives from Datagrid.
When I use the custom grid, it displays an overlapping column header behind others and I'm not sure why.
Here's a screenshot of my issue:

[image: Phantom column header overlapping actual columns]

Here's the XAML I use to call it:

```
<FDG:FilterDataGrid x:Name ="Jurisds"  MaxHeight="400" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HeadersVisibility="Column">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Region" Binding = "{Binding Region, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Municipality" Binding = "{Binding Jurisd, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Analysis" Binding = "{Binding AnalysisExists, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Brief" Binding = "{Binding StratBriefExists, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Missing Nbhds" Binding="{Binding MissingNbhds, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="nbhdsScreen"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="All Strats Approved" Binding="{Binding StratsApproved, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="stratsScreen"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</FDG:FilterDataGrid>
```

In the code-behind I set the ItemsSource to an object called **JurisdictionData**.
It looks like it's auto-generating a column header and then generating the proper columns.  Why is it creating this JurisdictionData header and how do I stop/remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DataGridColumnHeader object uses contains a DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter object.
The custom Data Grid that I wrote create a custom style for the DataGridColumnHeader, but not for the DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.
To correct the issue, I created a style for the DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter which contained only the ItemsPresenter in the custom datagrid Style.Resources section.

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--<DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer about [PART_FillerColumnHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976351/481143).